# how to sumit html form with haskell

Tags: html, haskell

I have a tedious sequence of operations that i would like to automate with Haskell.
It involves automatically clicking on a checkbox and then pushing a button. Then on the next page there's a radio button and a button. After these two steps I will get a final result page. I will then make some analysis and take some actions upon the result.

Which haskell libraries I can use ? Any sample code ?

**Step 1:**

[image: step1]

**Step 2:**

[image: step2]

Comment: BTW: If this is not easily done with Haskell, could anyone suggest any other languages that i can use ?

Comment: Are you wanting to automate the mouse?  If so, I would suggest autohotkey or Python with the SendKeys library if you're on Windows.  I don't know about other OSes

Comment: Dunno whether it's easily done with Haskell, but it's SUPER simple with in-browser Javascript. My Javascript is rusty, but something like `getElementById("id-of-checkbox-here").checked=true` is close enough to right that Googling should get you the rest of the way there.

Comment: Pourquoi est-ce que tu veux utiliser Haskell spécifiquement pour faire ça ?! Javascript me semble être la meilleure solution. (EN: should use JS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 things to do this:

1) Browser with full API, something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

2) Script which could use this API.